# Unknown algorithm name

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a matching problem, and have designed a method of solving it.
I need to know if an algorithm exists, if so the name, for the following situation, I have looked a lot, but cannot find anything. The closest I have come to is round robin, but thats not quite the same.

It is similar to some networking problems, but they generally don't get the most optimal route, they just settle for a good one. I need the most optimal.

This is a long read, and an unusual request for SO, but I cannot find a name for it anywhere.

**The Problem**
I have a pile of items.
Each item can be potentially connected to 1 or more other items.
Each item can only be paired once.
Each connection has a value.

I need to find what combination of pairs will result in the highest connection value.

**My Solution**
find all pairs for all items and store it in a map
take the first item and pair it with the first item in the maps value.
take the next item and pair it with the first unused item.
keep doing this until no more unused items exist.
save this combination or pairs total value.
change the last pair in the pair if possible.
compare to saved combination, if more save new combination
when the pair can no longer be changed, delete it and change the new last pair, find more possible pairs.
this keeps going until the combination list is reduced to size zero

The last saved combination is the best one.
(Fin)

Comment: Not sure, but probably this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Weighted_matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is basically just a maximum weighted matching.

For bipartite graphs, finding a maximum matching is easy. For arbitrary graphs, it's harder but still doable. Wikipedia suggests an algorithm by Edmonds called the Blossom Algorithm.

As for your algorithm, it's not clear exactly what you're doing, but it looks like a greedy assignment followed by hill climbing. I'm concerned that your algorithm isn't guaranteed to produce an optimal result. Have you actually proven this? How do you know it won't just get stuck in a local minima?

Comment: It attempts every single possibility without retrying a previous match. I have a program working with the above example and appears to bring the correct result up on each occasion. This is definitely a similar, it is very close to both this and the Gale-Shapely algorithm

Comment: Well unless you're using augmenting paths, it's probably incorrect or much slower than necessary. Can you post the actual code so I can see better exactly what you're doing?

Comment: After a lot of very quick reading, I agree with you, I would need to use the Blossom Algorithm, possibly with weighted matching. it is far more effective at finding the match I require. Thank you so much. I need to do more reading on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [Gale-Shapley algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem), which solves the stable marriage problem.

Comment: The question seems to show only 1 set. The algorithm seems to work on 2 sets.

Comment: @nhahtdh it does only use one set, but the values in the one set can be paired with other values in it. I just need to make sure the values are not paired more than once.

Comment: @Intern87: Then your graph is a general graph. The above algorithm seems to work only on bipartite graph - from what I read in the overview.

Comment: The Stable Marriage problem has nothing to do with maximum matchings, bipartite or not. They're seperate problems.